# curator 4.0.1 NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, apache-curator

I am using curator-framework version: 4.0.1 and calling CreateBuilder.creatingParentsIfNeed method. but got error show like below:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.framework.api.CreateBuilder.creatingParentsIfNeeded()Lorg/apache/curator/framework/api/ProtectACLCreateModePathAndBytesable

source code in curator-framework 4.0.1 do really have this method in the CreateBuilderMain.

the method signature in CreateBuilderMain is :

public ProtectACLCreateModeStatPathAndBytesable createParentsIfNeeded();

there is no maven conflicts, only curator-framework 4.0.1 in classpath.

why? pls help me solving this error

I found that ProtectedACLCreateModeStatPathAndBytesable implemented ProtectACLCreateModePathAndBytesable interface, is this why the error occurs?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557